# Power BI connect to Hive/Spark on Cloudera

Tags: apache-spark, hive, powerbi, cloudera, powerbi-datasource

I'm trying to connect Hive/Spark on Cloudera Private Cloud to Power BI Desktop. I want the data to keep being updated so I think the data connectivity mode should be DirectQuery. But the available connectors - Spark and Hive LLAP, are not supported by Cloudera as mentioned [here](https://docs.cloudera.com/cdp-private-cloud-base/7.1.7/hive-introduction/topics/hive-unsupported.html) - both LLAP and Spark thrift server are not supported. I know that ODBC in Power BI does not support DirectQuery. Does anyone know if there are any other options to build the connection?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself.. turns out I can use Hive LLAP as the connector.

Steps are shown below in case it helps someone else :)

1. Start HiveServer2 service if not, which listens to port 10000 by default
2. Can test it using beeline: `beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000`. Username and password are both `hive`. Try to select table, which should be ok.
3. In Power BI, select Hive LLAP as the connector.
4. Define parameters:
   `Server: <hostname>:10000`.
   `Database: <your db name>`.
   `Thrift Transport Protocol: Standard`.
   `Data Connectivity Mode: DirectQuery`.
5. You will be prompted to enter username and password. Type `hive` for both of them
6. A list of tables show up. Note that only internal tables data can show up. Select external tables will return error `MetaException(message:java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Storage schema reading not supported)`.

Comment: can you not use odbc ?